# How to debug python code running inside exec()

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, pdb, pudb

I'm trying to debug a plugin code that I'm running inside exec command

is there a way to debug it somehow?
for example:

```
code='''
breakpoint()
foo=5
print(foo)
'''
exec(code)
```

I want to stop before foo is printed,
and do `list` (pdb) command and see the code

Comment: You can divide the string to 2 different strings, then run only the first one, when you want to run everything just use exec on both

Comment: it's just an example to explain. 
in the real program exec is running plugin
that it dynamically loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
In [8]: code='import ipdb\nnfoo=5\nipdb.set_trace()\nprint(nfoo**2)'

In [9]: exec(code)
> <string>(4)<module>()

ipdb> nfoo
5
ipdb> nfoo = 6
ipdb> c
36
```

After `ipdb.set_trace()` ipdb will start. You can go to the next break using `c` or to next line with `n`.
check the following cheetsheet: [cheetsheet](https://wangchuan.github.io/coding/2017/07/12/ipdb-cheat-sheet.html)

```
code='import ipdb\nnfoo=5\nipdb.set_trace()\nprint(nfoo**2)'

In [13]: exec(code)
None
> <string>(4)<module>()

ipdb> nfoo
5
ipdb> nfoo = 6
ipdb> n
36
```

Note: it's easier to place your code inside a """ """.

Comment: thanks, 
but I still can't see the code `list` give me nothing

Answer (score 0):

found it
in pudb I can add :

`_MODULE_SOURCE_CODE = code`

or

`linecache.lazycache("<path>/code.py",module_globals= None)`

or

`linecache.cache[self.path] = (len(code), None, code.splitlines(True), path)`

or in VScode
I can just add the file to somewhere vscode can find it
and just set :

`"justMyCode": false,`
in launch.json file